# `apt-get update` cannot find Ubuntu servers

Tags: apt

Running `sudo apt-get update` fails on my server (that has an internet connection). Are the servers temporarily broken, or is my APT misconfigured and using old servers? In short, how do I fix this?

Here's the output:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux nematode 2.6.28-19-server #66-Ubuntu SMP Sat Oct 16 18:41:24 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/main Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/restricted Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/universe Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/main Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com jaunty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/main Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/universe Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com jaunty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jaunty-security/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Check my answer there as it worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources

Comment: BTW for me it was temporary network issue I don't know why , either Ubuntu server temporary banned me maybe because I'm using NAT IPv4 on my VPS .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Can you resolve any of those hosts from the command line?

```
jinx:775 Z$ ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.171) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from cassava.canonical.com (91.189.92.171): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=104 ms
```

If not, next step is to try `host -v`:

```
jinx:776 Z$ host -v us.archive.ubuntu.com
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14243
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 8, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.88.31
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.88.40
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.88.45
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.88.46
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.92.169
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.92.170
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.92.171
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  592     IN      A       91.189.88.30

Received 167 bytes from 10.211.55.1#53 in 37 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50130
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.         IN      AAAA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             1800    IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2011030301 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 100 bytes from 10.211.55.1#53 in 65 ms
Trying "us.archive.ubuntu.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54875
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.         IN      MX

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             1800    IN      SOA     ns1.canonical.com. hostmaster.canonical.com. 2011030301 10800 3600 604800 3600

Received 100 bytes from 10.211.55.1#53 in 62 ms
```

Look for errors returned by DNS servers.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the `ping` did not resolve either, but that I was able to ping via IP (resolved on a separate machine). Thanks to this help, and the comment by @ændrük, I discovered that somehow my DNS entries were completely useless. Fixing those fixed the problem.

Comment: Interesting problem: "host: command not found"
But I can't install it using apt without accepting non-verified packages.

Comment: no actual commands given here to fix. Just to state when it's working it's working correctly. If I can't ping and can't do `host -v` I'm doomed. What's next? No help whatsoever.

Comment: Running `host` with the optional DNS server option (`host -v us.archive.ubuntu.com 1.1.1.1`) can help. More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685094/why-host-command-returns-servfail

Answer (score 68):

It sounds like a DNS issue. To fix it, you need to ensure that

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

has good entries for DNS servers.

Google [has public DNS servers that you can use](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

So for example, you could add the following 2 lines to the top of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file (these point at the Google DNS servers) as detailed above:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Of course you'd need to be root to change this file, and make a backup before making any changes!

Comment: Not necessarily a good plan if you need to resolve addresses inside your own network. Fine if all each machine needs to access by name is located beyond your firewall.

Comment: @Ceisc - great point. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: In that file it says "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN" -- can you address this?

Comment: I can't say for sure - but it's still what Google suggests as the process for doing this [on their Google Public DNS Page](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#linux)

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: I don't believe this answer was the right solution for me after much struggle. Who might have erased my DNS entries?

Comment: I prioritized my VPN DNS first to get mine working. Haven't tested off VPN yet, but at least it works on. 

Comment: I had issues with updating my packages for weeks and this fixed it :D
Thanks

Comment: This is not a good solution. This file is resetted as soon as you reconnect to the same or another WAP. You would have to change it every single time.

Answer (score 20):

I know this thread is super old, but for anyone still looking on, I solved this problem by disconnecting and reconnecting to wireless access point.

Comment: this is the correct answer for the bulk of people who see this error ... you are simply not online ... get your WiFi connected and just issue your update command again ...  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me! Awesome simple answer that will probably be the solution for most people :)

Answer (score 11):

Often I shove 8.8.8.8 in my /etc/resolv.conf to fix this.  Esp when dealing with wonky cheap-cloud-provider-of-the-month (in this case linode) stuff.

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
#nameserver 72.14.179.5
#nameserver 72.14.188.5
```

These are Google's public DNS servers.   Yes, they probably track the heck out of those logs.   But the only site i tend to hit on those servers is git and ubuntu archives.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue `Err on apt-get update` ændrük hinted correctly.

I fixed my problem by changing a DNS address manually into the file `/etc/resolv.conf` to the DNS address of my operator.

Previously it was set to `192.168.0.254` by Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, as noted in my follow-up comment to the accepted answer, the problem was that my DNS was hosed and needed to be set to good values.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem in which:
`sudo apt-get update`
couldn't finish, and it had errors.
I've tried to restart my *cable modem*, and it worked. You can try restarting your cable modem, too.

Answer (score 3):

Turning off my VPN resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Check on your web browser to see if you can open web page "http://us.archive.ubuntu.com".
If yes, then it has to a network proxy settings problem.

Follow following steps on Ubuntu Desktop.

1. Go to System->Preferences->Network Proxy
2. Select “Manual Proxy Configuration”
3. Check “Use the same proxy for all protocols”
4. HTTP Proxy: , Port:
5. Hit Details and check “User Authentication”
6. Put Username and Password and close

After doing this, I was able to resolve these errors.

Comment: are you saying you resolved this by using a proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this same issue. Was working on a Virtual Machine and got tired of it constantly changing IP addresses. After setting static IP address, I did not set the DNS Nameservers and could no longer apt-get update. I needed to also add the name servers to the /etc/network/interfaces file. Found information on that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server). (How do I set the DNS Name Servers)

Next issue I ran into is that I could not ifdown and then ifup to reset the network interfaces. This code worked for me:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

More information about this problem can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service). (How to reset the network interfaces)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid DNS problem I had to add to `/etc/hosts` the IP of servers, for example

```
echo "91.189.91.24 security.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts 
echo "91.189.91.24 archive.ubuntu.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` (empty by default)
add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver YOUR DNS SERVER
```

Answer (score 1):

very simple:

1. look for  DNS address manually into file /etc/resolv.conf
2. cd /etc/network/
3. sudo nano interface
4. change nameservers
5. nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 not working with same routers (in my case hitron very bad

company ip routing not working at all )

you have to use ip address from /etc/resolv.conf

or use only your router ip in my case 192.168.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I have also solved this problem .
simply go to : system settings --> Network Proxy --> Method Automatic --> Apply SYstem Weide--> and put your admin password

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post but I just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a Dell E4310 and I ran into the same issue. I tried following some of the suggestions in this post but nothing worked so I decided to try changing the update server.

So in System Settings> Software & Updates, I changed the server from "Main" to the following:
http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/linux/ubuntu/archive

Now my updates are rolling without issues. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess there's no way to do this with the command line...? sigh

Answer (score 1):

*This will only apply to *some* people, in particular to people working on managed systems who are configured by others.*

When running `sudo apt update` (preferred), or `sudo apt-get update`, look for the following types of errors:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
Err:2 https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                         
  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
Err:3 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'apt-cacher.something1.something2'
...
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Notice the `'apt-cacher.something1.something2'` part. Grep for this in `/etc/apt` to see where this phrase might be found:

```bsh
grep -rn 'apt-cacher\.something1\.something2' "/etc/apt"
```

For me, I found a result in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy`. This means that my system has an `apt` proxy configured to re-route `apt update` and `apt install` commands through an alternate server. *If this alternate server is on a VPN, for instance, it won't be available if you're not VPNed in to that network, and you'll see the errors above.*

As a work-around, you can temporarily disable or enable this proxy by simply renaming this file as follows:

```bsh
# Disable the apt proxy by changing its name to have a ".bak" extension:
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy.bak

# Re-enable the apt proxy by removing the foreign ".bak" extension:
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy.bak /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
```

Now, when on the VPN, you can optionally re-enable the proxy, and when not on the VPN, you can disable the proxy. In this way your `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install` commands will be able to work in both cases.