# apt-get update fails due to "Unable to connect to localhost:8250" error

Tags: apt

Im trying to run sudo apt-get update. I know the server is up and my internet is working. any clues?

```
sudo apt-get update

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease  
Err http://archive.canonical.com oneiric InRelease
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to localhost:8250:
Err http://archive.canonical.com oneiric Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to localhost:8250:

Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release.gpg   
  Unable to connect to localhost:8250:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29071/apt-get-update-cannot-find-ubuntu-servers) and see if it helps? If yes, it's a duplicate. If not then it rules out DNS issues.

Comment: I can resolve the servers so I don't think that it is a DNS issue.

Comment: Have you installed tor or another similar proxy / IP shaping software?

Comment: yes awhile ago. I start poking around and found that http_proxy was set to localhost:8250. So I unset it and restarted, but apt-get is still trying to talk to localhost:8250

Comment: got it! i had to remove Acquire::http::proxy "http://localhost:8250/"; from /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: Please answer your question by hitting the 'Answer my own question' button so that others will know a solution was found. :)

Comment: Please mark your answer as `Answered` so that other people who come looking for an answer can know that it is actually a valid answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had to remove the line 
    `Acquire::http::proxy "localhost:8250/";;`
from /etc/apt/apt.conf

Comment: Please consider marking this question as answered by using the gray/green button left to the answer :)