# Ubuntu 12.10 not updating after upgrade from 12.04

Tags: software-center, update-manager

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 12.10. After this it is not updating . The software updater gives this error:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/Release.gpg Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/source/Sources Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/source/Sources Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
  :
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/universe/i18n/Translation-en Unable to connect to 10.4.42.15:8080:
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am not able to install anything from Software Center; it just asks to use this source and after that it just keeps on querying software sources and nothing happens.

The contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` are:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss / #SKSS
# deb-src http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss / #SKSS
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-proposed restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
```

Comment: You can try this out in the terminal `sudo apt-get update -f` and then `sudo apt-get update`. Hope this works.

Comment: after sudo apt-get update -f i am getting the same error

Comment: You may not be connecting to the internet, try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to 12.10 and it worked previously? Also what happens when you reboot your system and try to update?

Comment: no initially it was working correctly once but after after trying to install something from software center it was asking to add universe to the repository then i checked some of the ppa form the other software tab of the software sources , even though after undoing the things it's not updating , plz hep me out thanks in advance i love ubuntu do not want to switch to windows

Comment: @gunjanparashar - please add to your question what `10.4.42.15:8080` actually is - looks like you have a proxy - how have you set this up? Are you using a proxy like this Q&A? http://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy/118848#118848

Comment: Please check with your NETWORK PROXY settings. :) I solved it by changing the mode to normal as I use manual in the university and automatic at home. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem myself with Ubuntu 12.10. Be careful what you do to try to fix this - I ended up re-installing 12.04 to fix my machine. With that said, there is a bug report on Launchpad (sory, can't find it) that explains how Ubuntu 12.10 enables a DNS feature dnsdmasq by default, which messes up a lot of systems. This article explains how to disable dnsdmaq. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-disable-dnsmasq-in-ubuntu-12-04precise.html

Verbatim from the article: "

You need to edit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file

`$ gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

and comment out the following line from

`dns=dnsmasq`

to

`#dns=dnsmasq`

Save and exit the file

Now you need to network-manager using the following command

`$sudo restart network-manager`

"

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks bro for helping actually it was a problem with the proxy , thanks a lot

Comment: @gunjanparashar don't forget to mark an answer as "Accepted" if the answer helped.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution to the problem of ubuntu 12.10 not getting updated.
There actually was some problem with the proxy, so what I did was as follows:

I ran `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf`   to edit the `apt.conf` file, then

added the line below in the `apt.conf` file:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "false";
```

now everything is going as smoothly as it was.

Comment: thanks dear for the help really peoples who r giving the answers are making open source open source in real sense

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an internet issue. (`Unable to connect to X.X.X.X:XXXX:`) Try disabling your Firewall, and getting out from behind any proxies you may be using. If that doesn't fix it, I'd recommend changing your DNS. Your ISP may be giving you a lame DNS server (or maybe you manually set up a lame one. ;)

Anyway, to do this, just set your DNS servers to `208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220` (that's OpenDNS; there are others. Pick one that you like, but, most importantly, pick one that **works**.) If you don't know how to do this, detailed instructions can be found [here](https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/ubuntu).

Comment: i am using opendns ony

Comment: So... you're already using OpenDns? Try a different one, then. Also, do you normally have internet trouble? (e.g., frequent connection errors when surfing the web, Wi-Fi is unstable, etc.

Comment: Hey... another good DNS provider is Google's DNS - they don't screw up `nxdomain` like OpenDNS does. Primary server is `8.8.8.8` secondary `8.8.4.4`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this. When I ran

```
vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

I found in this file strange config with this the IP address 41.191.27.92:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://41.191.27.92:8080";
```

Delete this line and add:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "false";
```

After that, run:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
sudo apt-get update
```

And all works perfectly!

(I don't know why I found that IP address in the configuration file though.)

Answer (score 0):

In the Others tab of the Software Sources configuration, try unchecking the following

```
1. Canonical Partners (Source Code)
2. Independent (Source Code)
3. Independent
```

If it works, then great. But remember to periodically enable these repositories to check if they have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may want to check the routing tables if you have been playing with it at all.

```
route -n
```

Be sure the net 0.0.0.0 is configured for the correct gateway.
e.g.

```
root@home:/# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a known bug - just add using your preferred editor the following to your /etc/network/interfaces at the end of eth0 declaration (or whatever interface you use to connect to the network):

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
...
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dns-search domain.local
```

Then restart apache2 with `sudo apache2 restart`.