# Nvidia GTX 765M with Optimus Unclamed

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have tried alot of different ways to get my pc working with graphics card but hasnt got me anywhere.
I started off with installing ubuntu 12.04 for the first time which left me stuck at black login screen. (solved now).

I have tried bubmlebee method and installing driver from Nvidia directly but both didnt work. (I’ve got removed Nvidia* now since it didnt work)
with bumblebee I could not run optirun or prium

lspci -nn | grep -i vga

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
```

sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

lspci | grep NVIDIA

```
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] (rev a1)
```

PS: I used http://followthegeeks.com/a-noobs-guide-to-installing-nvidia-optimus-driver-in-ubuntu/ to solve black screen problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading driver from xorg edgers ppa(https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa).

Add the ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

upgrade your system

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Reinstall bumblebee.

If that doesn't solve your problem,

what is the error when you run `optirun`? include in your question.

A note : did you created this question yesterday? https://askubuntu.com/q/350922/35775 Don't create duplicate each day with different id that doesn't help here to get good answers.

Comment: optirun firefox :
[  745.002097] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[  745.002131] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

 I tried to delete the question because server didnt let me log in for some reason...so I had to create duplicate question sorry.

Comment: I"ve just checked and it is no longer unclaimed. However bumblebee stays off and overview doesnt show graphics at all...

Answer (score 0):

After many trials I finally found the problem related with the Kernel.
For me this makes the VGA work, you can give it a try. 
Jump over to a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-F1 :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-18-generic

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

sudo reboot
```

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Following Web-E answer, after a reboot

```
   sudo apt-get update
```

stopped working. I managed to get it going by following the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources), in other words by using

```
   cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
   sudo rm xorg-edgers-ppa-trusty.list
   sudo reboot
```