# Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: 16.10

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and connected to Wi-Fi which uses manual proxy.I can still surf on my browser.I got this error on following command:
    ~$ sudo apt-get update

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/135932/apt-get-update-failure-to-fetch-cant-connect-to-any-sources

Comment: Why would you have an "archive.ubuntu.com"  source in 16.10? Was it upgraded from 16.04?

Comment: no I installed 16.10.When I used my private data services I was able to update.The main issue  was connection. I changed network proxy , now its working fine.