# Error updating Ubuntu Server from 16.04.1 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, updates, 18.04

I'm trying to update an Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS.

I've updated/upgraded everything before starting the migration progress with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

which I've already run successfully on other servers.

BTW, it's blocking somewhere in the middle, stating that:

```
Failed to fetch
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkit2gtk/libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2_2.20.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
Connessione non riuscita [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

(*"Connessione non riuscita"* means *"Can't connect to"*)

The port is open, the IP is reachable, the telnet on port 80 is ok:

```
telnet 91.189.91.23 80
Trying 91.189.91.23...
Connected to 91.189.91.23.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

What could be the culprit?

Should I disable other PPAs as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/136448/137515)?

Comment: Why are you asking should you do what you've already found as the answer?

Comment: @L.D.James the error was different, and I've somehow fixed it without doing what described in that answer :|

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to resolve your problem.  Can share the solution, either by accepting the answer that resolved the issue, or adding an answer yourself so that others with a similar issue can easier find solutions.

Comment: @L.D.James I've already did it (before getting any comment and answer :) Unluckily, it's not an answer that satisfies me, because I've not understood what's happened... probably some kind of "network problem" or whatever. BTW I've solved that way, maybe it'll help someone. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the *nth* retry, I've run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and it completed the migration to 18.04 :|

I still don't know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Disable all PPA and Make sure that sourcelist `/etc/apt/source.list` contains only official repositories.

In Some cases if you are using firewall which block specific words in domain can block particular package from downloading ,you will stuck with that. Make sure that you allow traffic from that domain or you can whitelist particular URL.