# How do I configure my DNS settings in Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, dns, dnsmasq

According to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dns-configuration.html#dns-configuration-overview) it appears to be simple. However, `/etc/bind` does not exist on the default installation of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS server.

So, without installing any further software, how can configure DNS and remove dnsmasq on ubuntu server? I am quite familiar with `sudo` & `nano`.

Comment: Also take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq. bind IS a nameserver. If you need nameserver functionality on your server, you must install a nameserver. It would help if you could describe what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You were reading a manual to configure a DNS Server, not how to configure the DNS entries in the server. The manual you should have read are [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution)

Comment: I don't have the rep to post a comment on another answer, but in reply to Nullet's answer on September 17th 2013, this worked for me. I was thinking that there was a problem with my router (a cheap, ISP provided one). I also think it worth mentioning that on the dns-nameservers line, you should use the IP of *the public DNS.* Don't use the local address of the DNS, which is most likely on your router. I was connecting to the DNS on my router, which for some unknown reason wasn't working with my server. Instead, I found out where the DNS on my router was getting its information from, and set dn

Comment: I think there is a better answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/154538/82018 - basically you can override your dhcp settings to "prepend" a server in front of the ones you currently use. This is nice as you don't have to rely solely on the new server, you just give it precedence for lookups.

Comment: Related: [How do I set my DNS when resolv.conf is being overwritten?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128220/20226).

Answer (score 180, accepted):

### Set DNS Servers

You need to configure the `/etc/network/interfaces` file if you want to change your DNS server via the command line.

It should look something like this:

```
# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  


# The primary network interface  
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.X.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.X.X
dns-nameservers X.X.X.X
```

If you have more than one DNS server, just add a space between each:

```
dns-nameservers X.X.X.X Y.Y.Y.Y Z.Z.Z.Z
```

Just replace the Xs, Ys, and Zs with your own IPs of the DNS servers of choice, and when this is done, run this command to update the settings:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```

Hope this helps!

#### Update 2023

`ifconfig`, `ifdown`, `ifup` are deprecated. You can use:

```
sudo ip link set eth0 down && sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Make sure to use these commands in a single line with `&&` to avoid getting stuck out if you're using your system over a network or SSH.

Comment: Thanks - but how do I disable the dnsmasq as well ?

Comment: Yeah, dnsmasq is not installed on ubuntu server as default, if I remember correctly.

Comment: /etc/NetworkManager does not exist on the default install of ubuntu server 12.04, also I ran `ps -ef|grep dns` which returned no results _other than the grep command_ - Does that mean there is no dnsmasq running ?

Comment: OK - thank you for you help .. I have a lot to learn

Comment: tried @Nullet solution, but got this error,
`longtth@long-ubuntu-14:~$ sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`  
`interface eth0 not configured`  
`RTNETLINK answers: File exists`  
`Failed to bring up eth0.` Can you help me fix it ?

Comment: Here's my situation: I opened the file indicated in this answer and I had only the first 3 lines in it. I pasted in the rest. I ran the command and I got this: ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
 That concludes the output I received. If anyone has any thoughts that come to mind feel free to respond. I would like to know: what, generally speaking, am I to replace the X's in address and gateway with?

Comment: No command 'auto' found, did you mean:
Command 'uuto' from package 'uucp' (universe)
auto: command not found

Comment: @Mr.Hyde You shouldn't type these lines at terminal, you must to write them inside `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: Ensure that you are actually using eth0 and not something else like eth1. ifconfig.

Comment: One thing about dnsmasq:  If you use nmap and scan your own Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system it will show it running on port 53.  However, that is only on the loopback interface.  It is not configured to provide DNS to other systems by default.  This is done merely for caching.

Comment: Great answer - just adding that you don't have to use static configuration to configure. You can use DHCP and add the "dns-nameservers" line to get the result

Comment: if ifdown and ifup does not work use 'ip addr flush dev <interface>'.

Comment: This file does not seem to be existent in Ubuntu Server 22.04.

Answer (score 27):

Ubuntu 20.04 does not use `resolv.conf` anymore by default, however it can be installed by:

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

However if you are on some older Ubuntu version or some fork, you might be using [resolvconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/resolvconf.8.html) (a package that manages the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`).

In order to set dns-nameservers which won't be removed after reboot
add them in

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

like

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver x.x.y.y
```

And afer that just do

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: that path doesn't exist on my system I only have `/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/avahi-daemon` which loop for another bash script  `/usr/lib/avahi/avahi-daemon-check-dns.sh` all I want is to get ride of default   `192.168.1.1`  `DNS Servers:`

Comment: @SalemF just go-ahead and create that missing file...

Comment: , it's looks like , ubuntu uses different approach to handle dns setting I was only able change it from the GUI nm` which work after changing `DHCP` setting to `address only` and type dns address https://i.ibb.co/ysqwL0r/DHCP.png

Comment: What is `newer version` here. I use `20_04`, so it should work with it. Another thing: you write `base`, what about changing `head` - is head called before base?

Comment: @Timo base is used to be read defaults from and written in head, I think that head is overwritten every time you reboot...

Comment: I do [not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449246/72988) think so regarding overwriting of the `head`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer , thank you so much.

Answer (score 18):

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and unfortunately none of the other answers worked for me.

So, I will share the way I fixed the problem below:

First install [resolvconf](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/resolvconf), if it is not already installed

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

check that resolvconf service is started and enabled

```
sudo systemctl status resolvconf.service
```

If service is not enabled, you can start and enable using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf.service
```

Now edit the resolv.conf.d/head configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

and add your DNS addresses into it (for example, I use Google Public DNS, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now force resolvconf to run update scripts when invoked with -u

```
sudo resolvconf --enable-updates
```

Now run updates

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Now if you check the content of `resolv.conf` file using the following command

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

you must see your DNS configuration. If not, try the following commands and check again

```
sudo systemctl restart resolvconf.service
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

#### References

- https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resolvconf.8.html

Comment: sudo apt update requires you to have a DNS server already. If you don't have a DNS server configured then the update fails because it cannot resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com, etc.

Comment: @Rob You could initially add nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf`, then install what you need with `apt`. In my case, `/etc/resolv.conf` was reset after reboot.

Answer (score 12):

As of **20.04 Focal Fossa**, Ubuntu Server uses [systemd-resolved](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html) to manage nameserver configuration. */etc/resolv.conf is a static file and should not be edited.*

To configure your resolver, you set it in your netplan configuration file, like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.100/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
          addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]
```

For more information on how to use the netplan system, see the Ubuntu article on [network configuration](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration).

Answer (score 6):

### [NetworkManager TUI: `nmtui`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmtui.html)

Beside [this alternative using `nmcli connection edit`](https://askubuntu.com/a/721107/349837) you might like a more [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) approach with [`nmtui`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmtui.html), the GNOME's [<s>CLI</s>TUI](https://askubuntu.com/q/867416/349837) alternative to `nm-connection-editor`.

[image: screenshot nmtui main window]

[image: screenshot editing a connection]

<sup>**Note**: This answer is more related to Ubuntu Desktop, but since [the suitable question was marked as duplicate of this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/721080/349837) (incorrectly, IMO) I post it here.</sup>

Comment: Just run `sudo nmtui` from a terminal.