# ping: unknown host google.com in UBUNTU SERVER

Tags: 12.10, dns

I use Ubuntu Server 12.10. Why if I try:

> ping google.com
>
> ping bitbucket.org

or any other website I have:

> ping: unknown host google.com
>
> ping: unknown host bitbucket.org

EDIT:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=6.01 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=5.99 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=5.99 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=47 time=5.98 ms
```

`nano /etc/resolv.conf` is empty file

Comment: What's in `/etc/resolv.conf`? Any nameservers?

Comment: Could you also add output `ping 8.8.8.8`, and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @c0rp I updated question

Comment: Are you using DHCP or do you have configured a static IP?

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen How to check it?

Comment: Open `/etc/network/interfaces`. If there is a line like `iface eth0 inet dhcp` you're using DHCP, if there is a line like `iface eth0 inet static` you're using a static IP.

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen I use: `iface eth0 inet static`

Comment: Read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server) question. You need to set dns-nameservers.

Comment: @mamasi - thanks for enlightment, this is ending behind the moon in Australia ... - complaints possible to vipar@us.ntt.net - have we missed somthing ?! - boah ...

Answer (score 36):

If you're using a static IP you should also add DNS servers.

1. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
   ```
2. Below `iface eth0 inet static` add the following line:

   ```
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   ```

   This will use Google's DNS servers.
3. Restart your network:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```

**Note:** as chaos says, you can also edit `/etc/resolv.conf` but these changes will be overwritten on reobot.

**Note2:** Sometimes  `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` is not enough, but a full reboot helps.

Comment: I had to completely reboot, `/etc/init.d/networking restart` never seems to work for me, but that's ok because I'm glad it worked period.

Comment: This did not help to solve the issue on my end

Answer (score 3):

Create a file called `/etc/resolv.conf` write fill in the contents:

```
nameserver <ip-of-your-nameserver>
```

For example if your want to use googles dns-service:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Shouldn't the nameservers be specified as `dns-nameservers` in /etc/network/interfaces instead? 12.10 server should be running resolvconf by default, so there's a good chance any manual changes to /etc/resolv.conf will simple get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from you comments and output you are do not understand what is DNS.

> The Domain Name System (DNS) is a hierarchical distributed naming
> system for computers, services, or any resource connected to the
> Internet or a private network. It associates various information with
> domain names assigned to each of the participating entities. Most
> prominently, it translates easily memorized domain names to the
> numerical IP addresses needed for the purpose of locating computer
> services and devices worldwide. The Domain Name System is an essential
> component of the functionality of the Internet.

Other words if you want `ping google.com`, you need some service that will translate `google.com` into IP address `173.194.71.139` and then use it. Almost at any time you are querying server by domain name such as `google.com` DNS translates it to IP address.

Usually [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) configure this stuff for you. But in your case it is not, because you configure your network settings manually. And you forget to add `dns-nameserver`.

#### How to add dns-nameserver

Open NetworkManager (press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type "NM" and you will see Network Connection). Find your connection name, Edit Connections... | Edit... | IPv4 Settings | Additional DNS servers.
[image]
Here you can add your DNS, if you want google type 8.8.8.8, if you know your ISP DNS type it.

If you do not have GUI, [read this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)