# How to Change DNS of network from Terminal?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, dns

I know how to change the DNS of my network from GUI [Network Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/):

1. Right click on the network manager icon in the panel and choose "Edit connections..."
2. Select your connection from the wired or wireless tab, choose "Edit"
3. Choose IPv4 settings tab
4. Switch method to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"
5. Enter the DNS you want in the box "Additional DNS servers" and press "Apply"

How do I do exactly the same thing from Terminal?

Comment: The (current) TUI Network Manager alternative [is called `nmtui`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174193/349837).

Answer (score 22):

`nmcli connection show --active`  to obtain active connection name
`nmcli connection edit` *double tab to list available connections and chose appropriate*

> ```
>    nmcli> remove ipv4.dns  
>    nmcli> set ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
>    nmcli> set ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 (or other dns servers)      
>    nmcli> save
>    nmcli> quit
> ```

`nmcli connection down` *your_connection_name*
`nmcli connection up` *your_connection_name*

Comment: I think you also have to set `ipv4.ignore-auto-dns: yes`

Comment: Careful with nmcli connection down, if you are on a remote ssh session you can lose connection to the node!! I think is better to call /etc/init.d/network restart

Comment: There's also      **nmcli connection modify "Wired connection 1"  ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8"**    and the default 192.168.1.1 that most people see cant be removed because I'm pretty sure It's seen by    *ip route show*

Comment: If you care about speed and [privacy](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/9to0go/is_cloudflare_11111001_dns_safe/) you might prefer [using 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1 (Cloudflare)](https://1.1.1.1/) instead of [Google's one](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Comment: /etc/init.d/network restart did not work.  better yet, just do both commands with && between so it will come right back w/o losing connection. nmcli connection down && nmcli connection up

Comment: `nmcli connection up <your_connection_name>` by itself (no `down`) worked for me in Raspbian 10.