# nmcli connection verification failed

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, dns, nmcli

I'll paste the sequence of commands I'm trying to run to configure desktop Ubuntu 18.04 NetworkManager according to the answer [in this SO question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721080/how-to-change-dns-of-network-from-terminal). When I perform the steps [in the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/721080/how-to-change-dns-of-network-from-terminal) I end up with an *"Error: connection verification failed"*.

#### `nmcli connection show --active`

```
NAME          UUID                                  TYPE  DEVICE
LINKSYS99999  ...                                   wifi  wlp4s0
```

#### `nmcli connection edit`

```
Valid connection types: adsl, bluetooth, bond, bridge, cdma, dummy, generic, gsm, infiniband, ip-tunnel, macsec, macvlan, 802-11-olpc-mesh (olpc-mesh), ovs-bridge, ovs-interface, ovs-port, pppoe, team, tun, vlan, vpn, vxlan, wimax, 802-3-ethernet (ethernet), 802-11-wireless (wifi), bond-slave, bridge-slave, team-slave
```

#### Enter connection type: wifi

```
nmcli> remove ipv4.dns  
nmcli> set ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
nmcli> set ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
nmcli> save
```

> Error: connection verification failed: 802-11-wireless.ssid: property
>   is missing You may try running 'verify fix' to fix errors.

#### `nmcli> verify fix`

> Verify connection: 802-11-wireless.ssid: property is missing The error
>   cannot be fixed automatically.

What is going on and how do I fix it? Do I need to post all my wireless details according to [this SO guide](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify a connection ID or name to change an existing connection script, or add SSID info if creating a new connection script...

**man nmcli**

```
edit {[id | uuid | path] ID | [type type] [con-name name] }
    Edit an existing connection or add a new one, using an interactive
    editor.

    The existing connection is identified by its name, UUID or D-Bus
    path. If ID is ambiguous, a keyword id, uuid, or path can be used.
    See connection show above for the description of the ID-specifying
    keywords. Not providing an ID means that a new connection will be
    added.

    The interactive editor will guide you through the connection
    editing and allow you to change connection parameters according to
    your needs by means of a simple menu-driven interface. The editor
    indicates what settings and properties can be modified and provides
    in-line help.

    Available options:

    type
        type of the new connection; valid types are the same as for
        connection add command.

    con-name
        name for the new connection. It can be changed later in the
        editor.
```

**Post note**: if this is an Ubuntu **Desktop** installation, it's easier to use the [NetworkManager GUI](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/) to set up these settings.

Comment: in my case instead of typing `nmcli connection edit` into my terminal I should have typed `nmcli connection edit LINKSYS99999`? SSID is simply the network name I get when I `nmcli connection show --active` I believe. Is this correct? I can try when I'm next in front of the Ubuntu box. Not using GUI because I need to learn command line. Thanks

Comment: --active shows your current connection and connection name. I don't know if I'd edit an existing wireless connection via cli. Learning the cli is a good goal, but I'd make sure I fully understand the GUI first.

Comment: I did end up editing the active connection. Before you `save` Ubuntu will test the connection to make sure you didn't screw things up before applying changes. But your caution is warranted.