# Kde (Kubuntu) 17.04 error: "waiting for authorization"

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I recently update my kde 16.04 to KDE 17.04. During few day, everything was working well. But since yesterday, I am unable to connect to wifi. I just have something like: `waiting for authorization`. Can someone help me understand what is wrong with my system and solve the  issue?

**Update**

When I am oui on a public Wifi, my laptop is able to connect to wifi. This is really weird. I have tried with my phone access point, this is not working. I can't really understand why it is working with public wifi, but neither on my home wifi nor on my phone wifi.

**Update 2**

When I try to connect to my wifi, I just get a message like this :
[image]

can someone help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found solution. Kwallet was blocking my network but was not prompting for a password. Thank you all ... ;)

Comment: Thanks, the solution for me was to open my connections and in the current connection, in the Wi-Fi Security tab, to choose "Store password for all users (not encrypted)". Upon restart the network connected flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then just save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, type in `Y` (to say yes while saving changes) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and close the file, to make sure run the following command again and see if the changes you made are still there

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

if yes then close the terminal window open a new terminal window and run this following command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

And wifi should work again!

---

Another problem that might be causing this, is DNS issue, You'll need to first check if you have 8.8.8.8 already in your dns, if not the add DNS address using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/346845/665251)

Comment: the first solution did not work for me, how to check if I have 8.8.8.8 in my DNS ?

Comment: Go to kde settings / network! You should see dns somewhere! I've not used kde for a while so I can't tell you the exact location of the option

Comment: In the second answer seems like setting a fix IP address. Do I really have to set a fixed IP, since I would like to connect on many networking, without resetting everytime my ip?

Comment: Dns isn't static ip  and you can always configure it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: sorry, but when I try https://askubuntu.com/a/346845/600715 my network don't show any wifi.

Comment: I don't think the answer should be go into a random file and add stuff.  That's truly not acceptable for anybody who doesn't know exactly what they're doing.  And if they do know what they're doing, they probably wouldn't be reading this question.  Additionally there are probably 10 other possible issues causing this each with a different conclusion.  Input something like this in a configuration file and perhaps everything else breaks or you just lowered security.  Who knows.  Not ok.