# Change DNS to Coudflare 1.1.1.1 on Ubuntu 16.0.4 Server Hosted On AWS

Tags: server, dns

I'd like to take advantage of the recent Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 DNS service on my Ubuntu 16.04 based server. Any ideas how can I implement it permanently?

The reason is that

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

changes automatically and as the file states we shouldn't edit it manually.

What the best way to do so, for both ipv4 and ipv6?

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less "how do I set a static IP"

Follow this answer for a similar question on Ubuntu 12.04 which is more or less identical in application.

The relevant bit is your Name server

[How do I configure my DNS settings in Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server)

Though in keeping with many concerns of links relevant info from that question,
the correct file your looking for is

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and the part to modify should look similar to this

```
The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.X.X
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.X.X
dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1
```

This is the officially suggested method for changing/adding name servers from Ubuntu main help guides.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution

> To configure the resolver, add the IP addresses of the nameservers that are appropriate for your network in the file /etc/network/interfaces.