# Resolve.conf and network manager both set to use Local DNS but remote websites are resolved in Firefox. Why?

Tags: networking, server, firefox, network-manager, dns

I'm testing a dotnet core app set up to use NGINX as a reverse proxy. To test it, I set up Bind9 to resolve example.com to my LAN IP address. I've set the network manager DNS in the top right corner of Ubuntu 18.04 to use my IP as DNS and resolve.conf body to use the my IP as the DNS. When I dig example.com I get the local IP address:

```
dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54728
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: c3f027023efb13f917866a635b0e8feaa95ff6a3a3be7227 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        604800  IN  A   192.168.75.136

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        604800  IN  NS  ns.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns.example.com.     604800  IN  A   192.168.75.136

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.75.136#53(192.168.75.136)
;; WHEN: Wed May 30 04:50:02 PDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

However when I search in Firefox the online example.com is loaded. I flushed dns using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean restart
and
sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reload
```

Obviously something I did wrong because I can no longer edit the wired connection in the top right properties (it's gone). I setup no forwarders in named.conf.options so I shouldn't be able to resolve internet addresses.

in `/etc/networkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1`

```
[ipv4]
dns=192.168.75.136;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
```

generated resolve.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.75.136
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

There is no line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
saying `dns=dnsmasq`

---

I also added to `/etc/network/interfaces` after the loopback (based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server) post):

```
# The primary network interface  
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static  
address 192.168.75.136
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.75.2
dns-nameservers 192.168.75.136
```

and then ran
`sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

While undoing each step, I discovered that this last step is what caused eth0 to disappear and make the network manager wired settings in the top right of Ubuntu to no longer appear in 18.04

---

### sudo netstat -antup | grep LISTEN

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1538/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/named          
tcp        0      0 192.168.75.136:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/named          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      566/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1081/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/named          
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      1489/named          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1081/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      1489/named
```

NMCLI for some reason shows no dns server at all

### nmcli dev show eth0

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:0C:29:05:33:F4
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.75.136/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.75.2
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.75.2, mt =
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt =
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 192.168.75.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt 
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::20c:29ff:fe05:33f4/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table
```

var/run/systemd/resolve:
`nameserver 192.168.75.136`

### nmcli -t connection show --active

virbr0:4239285a-844c-4ec0-b671-c145089b52f1:bridge:virbr0

### nmcli con show 'virbr0' | grep dns

```
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      100
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      100
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
sticker592@ubuntu:~$ nmcli con show 'eth0' | grep dns
Error: eth0 - no such connection profile.
```

Comment: seems it is ubuntu 18.04, right? please edit your post and paste the output of `sudo netstat -antup | grep LISTEN`. This will show us if systemd-resolved is running

Comment: @cmak.fr ok. I'm reading the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf file and it is completely commented out. no dns

Comment: wrong file, look at `cat /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`

Comment: @cmak.fr Still shows local dns. Also I only set up one zone in bind9 and A record and ns record all pointing to local.

Comment: @cmak.fr output? Bind9 settings you mean? I'll add

Comment: Now, verify NM dns. Get active profile name and details ... Get the profile Name `nmcli -t  connection show --active` AND details `nmcli con show 'Profile Name' | grep dns`

Comment: @cmak.fr something is broken because the output shows no eth0,(shouldn't it?) see above

Comment: If you want to `resolve example.com to my lan ip address` isn't it sufficient to only edit */etc/hosts* file on your computer? Or by using a much simpler DNS-Resolver? It is not trivial to configure/setup Bind9.

Comment: @Ben good idea. I actually found entire textbooks on bind9, although I think I messed up on the step setting the Ubuntu configuration pointing to the dns server.

Comment: Just remove/revert Bind9 and simple add **127.0.0.1 example.com** and/or **127.0.0.1 www.example.com** to your **/etc/hosts** and you're done. Nothing more to to... I cannot add this as an answer, because this would not answer your particular question about resolve.conf and NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

*Very* simple solution: I forgot to clear the cache in Firefox:

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and
2. select to delete everything.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I was going to delete the question since I was just being careless/thoughtless, but then I figured maybe someone else might forget to do the same thing...