# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 failure

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade

I realize I am late to the game of upgrading my desktop machine LTS from 16.04 to 18.04. I did made a backup of my home directory using the backup utility and also copied some system directories to an external drive.

I completed all updates to 16.04 and then started the upgrade process using the automated method that repeatedly informed me 18.04 was available. After reading more about this, I realized I may have been better off using the command line.

I did get a number of messages indicating diffs in certain conf files and chose to replace most, if not all, of these rather than keeping them. There seems to be an issue with **systemd-shim**, which I cannot seem to remove or update. I did read the bug list on that issue, but the current state of system won't allow me to run those commands.

I suspect there are some 3rd party packages that might be contributing to my issues, but I do not know how to access that info at this stage. I do not think this is a video issue and I do not have an Nvidea card.

Regardless, the upgrade completed to a point, but not fully. I cannot restart into the system except for recovery mode. In recovery mode, I do enable networking, but upon going to clean-up, find space, or root, it appears domain names cannot resolve and therefore fail on apt-updates, etc.

I do have 18.04 on a DVD and can see and access the hard drive, so perhaps I might be able to execute something from there or from recovery mode.

I have tried a number of "solutions" but somewhat haphazardly. I would like to retain as much of my previous setup as possible, but will do whatever it takes.

I wish I could provide a boot list of where the process hangs, but at some point the screen goes blank. Perhaps there is a way to get this info?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, when I got too many problems via `do-release-upgrade` command, use an alternative way, backup package list and repos then clean install new OS. https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages, it's safer making Package.list helps me a lot. Note: the package list can't be applied on the different version of OS exactly. You can do the batch and think where it's stopped.

Comment: Sadaharu, thanks for your input. I will be using your method in the future. In the meantime I will detail the solution to my ordeal below.

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues that contributed to my problem.

In recovery mode, I realized I had internet connectivity, but DNS was not resolving. 
[DNS not working in recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096474/dns-not-working-in-recovery-terminal-mode)

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf
```

Next, fixing the systemd-shim error message issue was resolved here: [remove systemd-shim reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838491/dpkg-divert-error-rename-involves-overwriting-error-after-upgrading-from-16-04) I made sure I could run the find space and fix broken packages options in recovery mode.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.bak
```

Next, even though I am running on an HP box with an integrated Intel card, I suspect I may have used my Geforce card at one time, so I purged Nvidia drivers, even though I thought it would be futile. [purge nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Finally, I was able get to a login page (GDM3) and it did not respond to my password. I fixed this after realizing my Home directory was somehow changed to root.

Hope this helps someone, although I am late to the Bionic game.