# How can I prevent the "unable to resolve repository" apt installation failure?

Tags: apt, proxy

How can I avoid getting the error:

```
Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

when executing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install [package name]
```

Comment: but why only this repository is unable to be accessed behind a proxy?

Comment: Good question for whomever sets those rules. Usually your IT dept.

Comment: lol you are talking to it

Comment: but  not using the proxy didn't help I am afraid and my wifi is fine.

Comment: Try,  `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update`

Comment: @user535733 are you sure is a proxy issue? IMO is related to DNS server. He might need to use [an alternative DNS server like 1.1.1.1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174193/349837). That domain should resolve correctly, test [using `host us.archive.ubuntu.com 1.1.1.1`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/host.1.html).

Comment: @PabloBianchi quite possibly.