# How do i reset my networkconfig

Tags: networking, server, dns

Info:im running pihole in a docker on my server

I tried to set a static ip on my Ubuntu Server im running (Ubuntu Server 20.4 LTS).
I wanted to set a static ip address and I followed a tutorial where someone explained how to do that wit netplan so I had to work on a file/create one.
The file was called 01-network-manager-all.yaml and was in the Netplan directory.

This is what I had to write

```
# Let networkd manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.178.88/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

now I can't update anything can't download anything can't do nothing after that I tried configuring the dns server in a different way and followed this forum post

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server][1]

now nothing works and I would like to reset my networkconfig

Comment: I guess `sudo dpkg-reconfigure <package>` would reset the configuration. In your case the package might be networking.

Comment: You do NOT have a GUI on this server, correct? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /etc/netplan`.

Answer (score 0):

In the file 01-network-manager-all.yaml remove all except this lines:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

and execute

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan try
```

This should revert your changes until reboot.

Comment: what do you mean by This should revert your changes until reboot. 

what happens after reboot

Comment: After reboot your network return to the current non-working state. You can check if I am wrong