# how to get permission

Tags: docker

docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

Comment: if your trying to connect VIA Exec Console, replace Admin with Root, then you can connect.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add your user to the docker group by

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

then reboot and retry running Docker-related command.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to do anything more and in your environment has lots of users, just do the following and you would ready to use for all users,

```
[admin@localhost]$ systemctl enable --now docker
[admin@localhost]$ systemctl start docker
[admin@localhost]$ sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

By using the above you can use the "**docker**" command for every user.