# Set DNS server globally on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, dns, plasma

Kubuntu allows to setup DNS for a connection.

Each time I connect to a new connection, I have to set up DNS for it.

Is there a way to setup DNS globally?

Comment: Do you mean you have to update `/etc/resolv.conf` file each time you established a connection?

Comment: @ob2 No, I use system settings > connection > ipv4 & ipv6 tabs

Comment: @ob2 I don't know nothing about `/etc/resolv.conf` can this be a solution to my problem?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/346838/349837) (probably duplicate) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated which Kubuntu Version you're using. I'm using Kubuntu 22.04 in the instructions below, but this should also apply to 20.04 and newer.

You have a couple options on how to do this, `dhclient` or `nmcli`, and I'll let you decide which one you think is easier. With both options, you'll only have to do this once, as these configuration settings will survive a reboot.

---

## Option 1

Use `dhclient` to define DNS servers and ignore those pushed to you from your DHCP server.

1. Open *Konsole* and edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

   - Add the following line; adjust accordingly with your DNS servers.

     ```
     supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1;
     ```
   - Remove `domain-name-servers` after the `request` keyword.
   - The full output of my file is:

     ```
     $ cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf 
     # Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient.
     #
     # This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
     #       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
     #       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
     #       dhclient.
     #
     # Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
     #       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
     #       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
     #

     option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

     supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1;

     send host-name = gethostname();
     request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
             domain-search, host-name,
             dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
             netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
             rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

     timeout 300;
     ```
2. By default, Network Manager uses its internal DHCP client. Therefore, in order to override this and use *dhclient*, which will acknowledge the changes in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, create a new file called `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf` and add the following to it:

   ```
   [main]
   dhcp=dhclient
   ```
3. Restart Network Manager

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```
4. Release your current DHCP lease:

   ```
   sudo dhclient -r
   ```
5. Acquire new DHCP lease:

   ```
   sudo dhclient
   ```
6. Confirm your DNS servers by looking at output of `resolvectl`:

   ```
   $ resolvectl
   Global
          Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   resolv.conf mode: stub

   Link 2 (enp0s3)
       Current Scopes: DNS
            Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
   ```
7. Reboot and confirm DNS servers again with `resolvectl`.
8. You can confirm that Network Manager is using `dhclient` by running the following command:

   ```
   journalctl -b0 | grep dhclient
   ```

   Then look for a line such as the following:

   ```
   Mar 05 20:44:05 Kubuntu-22 NetworkManager[412]: <info>  [1709700245.8453] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
   ```

---

## Option 2

Use `nmcli` to define DNS servers and ignore those pushed to you from your DHCP server.

1. Find the "name" of your connection. Open *Konsole* and enter `nmcli connection`:

   ```
   $ nmcli connection
   NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
   Wired connection 1  eb3986c1-a90b-30d2-8f1d-1aedde7d9b16  ethernet  enp0s3
   ```

   In the output above, the connection is named "*Wired connection 1*". I'll use that in the examples below. Adjust accordingly for your connection name.
2. Ignore DNS servers pushed to you from your DHCP server:

   ```
   nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
   ```
3. Add DNS servers to your connection:

   ```
   nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1"
   ```
4. Reload your connection:

   ```
   sudo nmcli connection reload
   ```
5. Restart Network Manager:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
   ```

At this point, your DNS servers are set for your connection. Look at the output of `resolvectl`. Notice that the DNS servers I've defined, `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1`, are set for Link 2 (enp0s3), which is associated with "*Wired connection 1*".

```
$ resolvectl
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s3)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
          DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

By implementing these changes, a config file is created in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`. Take a look at the file created by the above commands:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/'Wired connection 1.nmconnection' 
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=eb3986c1-a90b-30d2-8f1d-1aedde7d9b16
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=enp0s3
timestamp=1709695374

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
dns=8.8.8.8;1.1.1.1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]
```

For more information:

- Ubuntu website:

  [nmcli manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nmcli.1.html)

  [Network Manager](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager)
- Arch Linux website:

  [Network Manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager)

  [Description and Settings for nmcli](https://man.archlinux.org/man/nm-settings.5)

---