# apt-get install python-software-properties not working

Tags: apt, python

I'm new here, new to Ubuntu, and basically new too anything related to Linux.

I am trying to install zoneminder and I am following this wiki page: http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.28.0_the_easy_way and when I try to install `python-software-properties` I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-pycurl
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pycurl python-software-properties
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 67.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 358 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python-pycurl amd64 7.19.3-0ubuntu3
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe python-software-properties all 0.92.37.3
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pycurl/python-pycurl_7.19.3-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/software-properties/python-software-properties_0.92.37.3_all.deb
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have tried apt-get update `--fix missing` and it didn't fix the problem. Any help is appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [apt-get update cannot find ubuntu servers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29071/apt-get-update-cannot-find-ubuntu-servers)

Answer (score 2):

if you installed using 12.04.5 server or alternate install then it usually can be fixed with

```
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
```

FYI: Here is the cause of the problem
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-setup/+bug/1434699

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your DNS server and/your internet provider as indicated by the error messages `Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'`

Often these sort of problems are temporary in nature and if you try again later it would just work. If it doesn't contact your ISP and point them to this page.

Comment: I had to set a static ip and i have may put the wrong dns numbers in. i will see if this will fix it.

Comment: I put the right dns numbers and im still getting the same error. any other ideas?

Comment: Edit file `/etc/resolv.conf` and put the nameserver value to 8.8.8.8 (i.e. `nameserver 8.8.8.8`) and see if it will help. BTW 8.8.8.8 is a nameserver maintained by google.