# APT "Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'"

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt, server

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am unable to use `apt-get update` command. I am getting the below error:

```
support@node:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch 
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 162.70.211.177
        netmask 255.255.255.128
        network 162.70.211.128
        broadcast 162.70.211.255
        gateway 162.70.211.129
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        dns-search local
```

Comment: looks like a connection error.... did you try running again?

Comment: 14.04 should still be supported for another year, right? so this https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release doesn't apply?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte yea. I tried multiple times but it gives the same error again and again

Comment: can you ping the servers? could be DNS issue... see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29071/apt-get-update-cannot-find-ubuntu-servers

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte cannot ping 

   `support@node:~$ ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
    ping: unknown host us.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: Try pinging an ip (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`)

Comment: @velix I am able to ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: probably DNS issue... add the google dns servers to /etc/network/interfaces -> dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 per the second answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping IP addresses but not domain names, you have a problem with your DNS. Adding the google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to /etc/network/interfaces and restarting should solve your problem:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    . . .
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Reference: [See Answer #2 Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Comment: did the following change but still not working

Comment: can you post your /etc/network/interfaces content into your question?

Comment: updated the content for /etc/network/interfaces in the question